# requirements to deploy the mvc 3 application to the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, setup-deployment

I want to deploy the application in the Windows Server 2008 R2. But I am wondering if I need to install the .Net Framework 4.0 since the version available in the server is 2.0? Do I need also to install the MVC Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to install MVC, only dlls can do the task

there are different ways to do it, see  links

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg286946.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/18/running-an-asp-net-mvc-3-app-on-a-web-server-that-doesn-t-have-asp-net-mvc-3-installed.aspx

Comment: thank you, but Do I need to install the .Net Framework 4.0, since the server doesn't have this?

Comment: yes, you need to install it. and note that you can run .net FW 2.O AND 4.0 side by side on the same server

Answer (score 1):

You may use the ASP.NET MVC3 installer,

or simply copy the required dlls into bin directory of your web application

such as System.Web.Mvc.dll,
System.Web.Helpers.dll,
System.Web.Razor.dll,
System.Web.WebPages.dll, 
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll,
System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll,
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll,
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll